# Maven MOJO: is it possible to customize the auto-generated plugin.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven MOJO and I wish to modify the auto generated plugin.xml.
For example, I would like to have a different version written there and have a different set of dependencies.

Is is possible to customize this file? I've tried using the maven-plugin-plugin:3.5:descriptor goal in my pom like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mojoDependencies>com.company:something</mojoDependencies>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It seems to have zero effect.

Can anyone provide an example to how it can be done?

Comment: First what kind of problem is your plugin intended to solve? Furthermore what would you like to achieve by the configuration ? What is the problem?

Comment: Basically my plugin processes some files within the project and generated some other type of files.
When I build my plugin it is depended on some JAR.
The machine I wish to deploy to, has a different JAR which provides the needed classes.
I supply an appropriate pom.xml file alongside the Maven plugin JAR and on the deploy machine I expect the plugin to be installed using the provided pom, but now there is a mismatch in the information between the supplied pom and the plugin.xml inside my plugin. 
So I wish to control the generated plugin.xml file to make it match the pom

Comment: The dependencies of your plugin are controlled by the pom file...